# Click any element in array of root folder and get its path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to get the current clicked folder from an array of my app's root folder and read it with readdirSync and I can't find anything helpful.

So far, what I got is only the index number on click, but I can't read it because it is not a string.

Here is what I have now :

```
const fs = require('fs');

$('li').click(function() {

    file = $('li').index(this);
    fs.readdirSync(file);
    console.log(file);

})
```

My app

[image: my app]

So, to read my root folder I have : `let files = fs.readdirSync('.')` and a `forEach` function. I want to click on "js" folder for example, and display what is inside it but I don't know how.

I'm new to electron and node.js :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code will be used in the code that follows after:

```
  const fileSystem = require("fs");
  const getDirectoryContents = path => fileSystem.readdirSync(path);
```

Assuming your `ul` has an id called `main`, this is what I'd do:

```
$("#main li").on("click", function clickHandler() {
    const $clickedElement = $(this);
    const elementName = $clickedElement.text(); // gets the text that was clicked
    const fsEntry = fileSystem.statSync(elementName);
    if (fsEntry.isDirectory()) { // retrieve the contents only if the clicked text represents a folder
      const files = ['<ul>'].concat(
        getDirectoryContents(elementName).map(entryName => `<li>${entryName}</li>`),
        '</ul>'
      ).join('');
      $clickedElement.append(files); // not exactly the best way to do it, but does the job
    } else {
      // do something if the entry is a file
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps.